# kafka-node npm install MacOS: Build error - "#include nested too deeply"

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, apache-kafka, node-gyp

I had zero problems installing kafka-node in this environment, up until today. Now I'm getting a build error upon installing.

I don't know much about the internals of this module, but it appears to have a build process based on node-gyp.

I've been using it for a month now and have built it several times on different Macs. Suddenly, it just won't work.

**Environment**

- Node version: 9.4.0
- Kafka-node version: 2.4.1
- MacOS High Sierra
- Xcode 9.2

**Output:**

```
npm install kafka-node --save

> snappy@6.0.1 install /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/Company/Project/projects/my-library-name/node_modules/snappy
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.4/snappy-sinksource.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.4/snappy-stubs-internal.o
In file included from ../deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.4/snappy-stubs-internal.cc:29:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:640:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:629:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/typeinfo:61:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:82:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:86:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:65:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:72:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:2:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <stddef.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <stdint.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:72:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <sys/types.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:76:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <limits.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:82:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <inttypes.h>
          ^
In file included from ../deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.4/snappy-stubs-internal.cc:29:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:640:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:629:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/typeinfo:61:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:82:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:86:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:65:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:197:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:198:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:199:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:200:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:201:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pageins;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_wired_size;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_resident_size;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:205:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:206:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:211:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:212:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:213:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:214:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-1.1.4/snappy-stubs-internal.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/Company/Project/projects/my-library-name/node_modules/snappy
gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN fuzion-stream-lib@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: snappy@6.0.1 (node_modules/snappy):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: snappy@6.0.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Having *similar* (but not exactly the same) issues - did you find a solution?

Comment: @Michael Nothing yet. I wish I could because I'm now stuck, as a result.

Comment: You may want to confirm you have libssl installed....

Comment: @Michael Do have it. I upgraded it from n to o just now and the issue doesn't go away. Thanks though!

Comment: No worries.  We are in the process of moving to https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka and had issues which node-gyp there (for librdkafka) until we installed libssl (and pkg-config)...